# Does Fujifilm instant film work with Polaroid instant 10

Tags: fujifilm, polaroid, instant-camera

I have Polaroid instant 10 camer, like this:

http://en.polaroid-passion.com/polaroid-type-80-cameras.php?id=179

I have understood, that some of the Fujifilm instant films could be compatible, but is it so? And which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Polaroid Instant 10 takes type 80 film. Fujifilm produces (though they just announced the discontinuation of production) FP-100c which is a different size than type 80. FP-100c and the earlier FP-3000b and FP-100b are all the same size as type 100 film. Unfortunately there is no film currently being produced to fit cameras that take type 80 pack film.